# Non-redundant way to use a single controller to collect the exact same data from four models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller

I just don't want to copy and paste. There has to be a better way.

I've got a single controller that uses a single model to collect some data into two arrays. Then I have a single view (index.html.erb) that uses those arrays in a graph. It's absurdly simple. This is the whole view. The arrays from the controller are, obviously, @buildStepArrays and @buildDates.

```
<% chart = GChart.line(:title=>"Build Times", :size=>"1000x300", :data=>@buildStepArrays, :colors=>@colors, :legend=>@buildDates) %>
<% chart.axis(:left) %>
<%= image_tag chart.to_url %>
```

Controller is here

```
def index
    # These three arrays should be the same size
    @buildStepArrays = []
    @buildDates = []
    @totalBuildTimes = []  

    @latestId = Env2.last().BuildId
    @latestId = @latestId - 1

    for buildNumber in (@latestId-4)..@latestId
        @build = Env2.find_all_by_BuildId(buildNumber)
        totalTime = 0
        @currentBuildTimes = []
        for step in @build
            @currentBuildTimes << step.Minutes
            totalTime += step.Minutes.to_i
        end
        @buildStepArrays << @currentBuildTimes.map { |e| e.nil? ? 0 : e }
        @totalBuildTimes << totalTime
        @buildDates << @build.last().Created
        @colors = [["FF1300"], ["FF8C00"], ["FFFF00"], ["00CC00"], ["1240AB"]]
    end
end
```

What I would like to do is collect the **exact** same data from four models (same table in four different databases), not just one, and then show four graphs on the view instead of one. I don't know enough about Rails to know how to do this correctly. My only idea right now is to literally copy and paste the code inside my controller four times and change the variable names around. That is totally awful. What am I "supposed" to do?

Comment: Can you show the code in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Controller

```
def index
  @data = [Env1, Env2, Env3].map do |model|
    data = Hash.new
    data[:title] = "Build Times"
    data[:buildStepArrays] = []
    data[:buildDates] = []
    data[:totalBuildTimes] = []  

    data[:latestId] = model.last().BuildId
    data[:latestId] = data[:latestId] - 1

    for buildNumber in (data[:latestId]-4)..data[:latestId]
      data[:build] = model.find_all_by_BuildId(buildNumber)
      totalTime = 0
      data[:currentBuildTimes] = []
      for step in data[:build]
        data[:currentBuildTimes] << step.Minutes
        totalTime += step.Minutes.to_i
      end
      data[:buildStepArrays] << data[:currentBuildTimes].map { |e| e.nil? ? 0 : e }
      data[:totalBuildTimes] << totalTime
      data[:buildDates] << data[:build].last().Created
      data[:colors] = [["FF1300"], ["FF8C00"], ["FFFF00"], ["00CC00"], ["1240AB"]]
    end
  end
end
```

View

```
<% @data.each do |data| %>
  <% chart = GChart.line(:title=>data[:title], :size=>"1000x300", :data=>data[:buildStepArrays], :colors=>data[:colors], :legend=>data[:buildDates]) %>
  <% chart.axis(:left) %>
  <%= image_tag chart.to_url %>
<% end %>
```

---

I just trowed everything into the Hash but you better just put there you need to render in the view.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to create modules that hold code that is repeated, which is your case, is at least four times. What you would do is still create the controller files for each model...

```
class ModelAController < ApplicationController
  include BasicActions
  before_filter get_model      

  def get_model
    @model = self.class.to_s.gsub("Controller").classify
  end
end
```

You'll notice the 'get_model' method, which is important, since it sets the @model variable to hold the class you are dealing with.  I didn't confirm the exact code to get just the coass name text, so you'll have to play around with that. You'll probably be using @model inside your module.

Here is a skeletal module:

```
module BasicActions

  def some_method
    ...
  end
```

You'll still need all of related views for each action that renders, but there are ways to limit that to just one set of views...

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant solution would probably be to use a presenter. Presenters can help you either clean up logic from your views or clean up too many instance variables from your controller. The latter seems to be the case here.

Using a presenter would allow you to:

- Optimize database queries, in your case doing a single query from all four databases.
- Make testing your code much easier by allowing you to write tests directly to the actions in your presenters.

It's hard to say exactly how you would build your presenters without knowing more about your app, but I can give you some general guidelines with mockup code just to show you how it works.

Instead of simply defining your instance variables from the four different models, you would define a new action in your controller similar to this:

/app/controllers/charts_controller.rb

```
...
def show
    @data = ChartPresenter.new(argument)
end
...
```

And then you would define the new presenter class in a new directory, with actions corresponding to the output you need in your views:

/app/presenters/chart_presenter.rb

```
class ChartPresenter

    def initialize(data)
        @data = data
    end

    def method_name
        ...
    end

end
```

/app/views/chart.html.erb

```
...
<%= @data.method_name %>
...
```

#### References

- [RailsCasts #287 - Presenters from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch) - only available for RailsCasts Pro subscribers
- [Simplifying your Ruby on Rails code: Presenter pattern, cells plugin](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/simplifying-your-ruby-on-rails-code/) - it's from 2009, but might be useful.

#### P.S.

Most tutorials will tell you to edit your `config/application.rb` to set `config.autoload_paths` to your presenters' directory. However, in Rails 3 **this is no longer necessary** since everything under `/app/*` is automatically added.